# Line breaks cause too many empty lines in the Information box

Tags: front-end, debugging

```
$Version
13.0.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)
```

When there are many `*Values` with line breaks, the `Information` box will contain lots of empty lines on the top. For example,

```
Clear@x
Table[x[0,i]=RandomWord[i],{i,Range[10]}];
x//Information
```

[image]

and it's incovenient to check the definitions.

##### Question:

Is there a way to get rid of the empty lines in the `Information` box?

##### What I tried:

I tried to read the documents, but found no clue to modify it. The `Options` of `Information`: `{ResolveContextAliases -> True}`.

##### Why I want:

Usually I use `foo//Information//Dynamic` to monitor the change of definitions of specfic symbols. I tried e.g. `foo//Definition//Dynamic`, and it seems that only `Information` will update the definitions.

##### Question 2:

If the appearance of `Information` cannot be modified? Are there convenient ways to monitor the definitions `Dynamic`-ally?

Comment: I don't see that empty space. What version are you using?

Comment: @lericr "13.0.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 28, 2022)" I'll add this into the question.

Comment: For the record, I also see a bunch of empty lines with `$Version` being `13.0.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (December 3, 2021)`. If it doesn't show up on windows or linux, it might be a mac problem, possibly, not an ARM problem. @lericr what version did you not see the empty space on?

Comment: Notice also that these don't seem to be newlines. If you move around the text cursor within the rendered `InformationData`, you see it jump from `Definitions` down to the items present.

Comment: I'm using 13.1.0.0